# mysql JSON_SET can't insert into column with NULL value(5.7+)

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

I am exploring the JSON funcions of newer mysql server.  But run into a very rudimentary issue.

**How do I insert {"key":"value"} into a JSON column when I don't know if the current value is NULL or not?**

The table is for illustration only:

```
CREATE TABLE `testjson` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `extra` JSON NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Test data with NULL and valid json value.

```
| id | extra             | 
| -: | -                 | 
| 1  | (NULL)            | 
| 2  | {"name": "james"} |
```

Desired outcome:

```
| id | extra                        | 
| -: | -                            | 
| 1  | {"age": 87}                  | 
| 2  | {"age": 87, "name": "james"} |
```

Now, I try to add {"age":87} into all rows:

```
UPDATE testjson
    SET extra = JSON_SET(extra,'$.age', 87)
;

UPDATE testjson
    SET extra = JSON_MERGE(extra,JSON_OBJECT('age', 87)),
;
```

None of above updates the NULL field.  Tried to set the column default to `{}`, but it is not allowed.

Because NULL is not valid JSON data, none of the mysql JSON funcion works:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html

My current work around is to set NULL to `{}` before insert, but it is stupid. An simple update should not use two queries.

How do you guys handle this?

Comment: Check if you got a NULL value (control flow functions), and if so use one of the functions that _create_ JSON ...? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html

Comment: Try: `UPDATE \`testjson\` SET \`extra\` = IF(\`extra\` IS NULL, JSON_OBJECT('age', 87), JSON_INSERT(\`extra\`, '$.age', 87));`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

`UPDATE testjson SET extra = JSON_SET(COALESCE(extra, '{}'), '$.age', 87);`

Comment: very nice! Thanks!

Comment: just an admonition, I ran into the fact my fields weren't `null` in the mysql-way, but `null` in JSON-way, i.e. the field content was stringly `"null"` therefore that COALESCE didn't work outta the box for me.

Comment: follow-up: I found no other way than `… SET extra = JSON_SET(IF(JSON_TYPE(extra) = 'NULL', "{}", extra), "$.age", 87)` (adapted to your sample ofc)

Comment: @AdrianFöder it should be `SET extra = JSON_SET(IF(JSON_TYPE(extra) is NULL, "{}", extra), "$.age", 87)`

Answer (score 4):

```
SET extra = JSON_SET(IFNULL(extra, "{}"), "$.age", 87)
```

Comment: Love this solution, super simple :)